# REST service to create dynamic table into database from Hibernate

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am writing RESTful web service to insert dynamic table into the database. I am going wrong somewhere in that and it is not working what i am trying to do. can someone please figure out and correct me where I am doing wrong?

Persistance class:

```
public void createTable(String tableName, List<String> columns, List<String> datatypes) {

         StringBuilder createTableQuery = new StringBuilder("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + tableName + "` (");
          columns = new ArrayList<>();


         for (int i=0;i<columns.size();i++) {

                 createTableQuery.append("`" + columns + "` ");
                 createTableQuery.append(datatypes + ", ");
            }

             //To replace last ',' character and place the bracket.
            createTableQuery.replace(createTableQuery.lastIndexOf(","),createTableQuery.length(), ")");
        eTableQuery);

            Session session = null;
            Transaction transaction = null;
            try {

                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                int count = session.createSQLQuery(createTableQuery.toString()).executeUpdate();   

                transaction.commit();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                transaction.rollback();         
            }
    }
```

Service Class:

```
@POST
    @Path("/selfbi/addtable")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTable(JSONObject jsonObject, @QueryParam("uniqueid") String uniqueid, @QueryParam("sheetname") String sheetname) throws JSONException  {
        Response res = null;
        try{
        String tableName = "";
        if(jsonObject.has("tableName")){
            tableName = jsonObject.getString("tableName");
        }

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("columns");

        List<String> col = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            if (jsonArray != null) { 
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) { 
                col.add(jsonArray.getString(i));    
            } 
        }


        JSONArray json = jsonObject.getJSONArray("datatypes");
        List<String> dtype = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        if (json != null) { 
            for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++) { 
                dtype.add(json.getString(i));   
            } 
        }


        restService.createTable(tableName, col, dtype);



        res = Response.status(Status.CREATED).build();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("service------>>>"+res);
        return res;
    }
```

ERROR in Console:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.replace(AbstractStringBuilder.java:789)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.replace(StringBuilder.java:266)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.service.ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl.createTable(ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl.java:7843)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.createTable(Unknown Source)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.restservice.service.RestServiceImpl.createTable(RestServiceImpl.java:2751)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.restservice.service.RestrsService.createTable(RestrsService.java:428)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

If you dont want to answer please ignore it instead of down voting/blocking it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of your error (probably not), but when adding the column definitions, make sure to append the current element from the `columns` and `datatypes` list to the `StringBuilder`, instead of the lists themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the fact that you've re-assigned the `columns` variable with a new, empty `ArrayList`. This means no columns will be added to the query, and such `lastIndexOf()` will return -1.

Comment: Yes you are right. Any code suggestion to resolve it?

Comment: How about removing the statement `columns = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: The offending statement is in the `createTable` method of the persistence class; it re-assigns one of its input parameters a new (and thus empty) list. Marking the method parameter `final` ensures re-assignment is not possible, by the way.

Comment: Removing columns = new ArrayList<>(); solved the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. But still table is not inserting into the database.

Comment: Check my comment right below your question (about the elements in the list vs. the list itself).

Answer (score 1):

Replacing last comma with bracket won't work if `columns.size()` is zero. Do something like:

```
if (columns.size() > 0){
createTableQuery.replace(createTableQuery.lastIndexOf(","),createTableQuery.length(), ")");
}
```